# MySQL Query Show Rows with columns data even if not exists

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Table with the following columns

```
id
action
ip
```

The action column can contain several values such as ( edit , delete, add etc)

I want to perform a MySQL Query and get some data based on the action value i will provive no matter if the action value exists or not.

For example the following query

```
SELECT ip,COUNT(*) as total_actions FROM table 
WHERE action IN ('edit','delete') group by ip;
```

This query returns data based on the action column and for example if there is no entry for `edit action` it will not be printed in the results.

Instead, **for the values i write in the IN statement i want to get their COUNT Values** and **for the values that don't exists the count should be 0.**

How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to count `ip`s that match *everything* in the `where` clause.  Well, you can't quite do that with the `where` clause.

You can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ip,
       SUM(action IN ('edit', 'delete'))
FROM table
GROUP BY ip;
```

Comment: no, i want to get the results for each action i specified even if there is no such action in the table. But all these in seperate rows... It's hard for me to explain.